# Return result of Invoking a Delegate from another thread

Tags: multithreading, delegates, c++-cli, invoke

I've got a GUI with a TabControl. Each new TabPage is created via a new Thread. I want to call `this->tabControl->TabCount`, but the `tabControl` is owned by a thread other than the one I'm calling from. Therefore, I need to Invoke a delegate. However, all the examples I find online show printing to `std::cout` from each of the delegate methods. I need a return value, in this case an `int`.

```
delegate int MyDel();
int InvokeTabCount()
{
    if (this->InvokeRequired)
    {
        MyDel^ del = gcnew MyDel(this, &MyTabControl::InvokeTabCount);
        auto temp = this->Invoke(del); // can't just "return this->Invoke(del)"
        return temp; // Invoke() returns a System::Object^
    }
    else
    {
        return this->tabControl->TabCount;
    }
}

void CreateNewTab()
{
    // do stuff
    this->tabControl->TabPages->Insert(InvokeTabCount() - 1, myNewTab); // insert a tab
    this->tabControl->SelectTab(InvokeTabCount() - 2); // OutOfBounds and tabPageNew
}

System::Void MethodToAddNewTabPage() //actually a click event but whatever
{
    System::Threading::Thread^ newThread = 
        gcnew System::Threading::Thread(
            gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(this, &MyTabControl::CreateNewTab));
    newThread->Start();
}
```

Currently, my `InvokeTabCount()` method is returning `-1` when I simply `this->Invoke(del)` without returning it. And I am unable to `return` it because my method expects to return an `int` instead of a `System::Object^` which is what `Invoke()` returns. However, when debugging I find that `auto temp` contains the value `2` which is correct. And `temp->ToString()` contains the value `"2"` which would also be correct.

**How do I `return this->Invoke(del)`?**

---

Do I need to set the value of a global variable from within my `InvokeTabCount()` method? I suppose I could find a way to translate from `System::String^` to `std::string` to utilize `std::stoi()`, but that seems like an odd workaround.

---

**Current solution:**

```
delegate int MyDel();
int InvokeTabCount()
{
    if (this->InvokeRequired)
    {
        MyDel^ del = gcnew MyDel(this, &MyTabControl::InvokeTabCount);
        auto temp = this->Invoke(del);
        return int::Parse(temp->ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        return this->tabControl->TabCount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result is an integer, boxed and contained in an `Object^` reference. You should be able to simply cast it to `int`.

If you want to be extra safe, do a null check and verify that `temp->GetType()` returns `int::typeid`, but that's probably overkill since you're creating the delegate (still in the typed form) right there.